# parent details in same row conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Called `EmployeeLevel`

```
Id     Position ShouldApproveLeave
1000     1         0
2000     2         1
3000     3         0
4000     4         0
```

Note that the bool column `ShouldApproveLeave` is true for only one row

I have a table `Employee` with the following structure with `LevelId` as foreign key to `EmployeeLevel`

```
Id     ParentId  Name   LevelId
1000   NULL      Jack    1000
2000   1000      John    2000
3000   2000      Nick    3000
4000   3000      James   4000
```

I need a query to get employee details, position details as well as the manager responsible for his leave approval as below

query (id = 4000)

```
Id     Name    LevelPosition  LeaveApprovalLevel LeaveApprovingManager 
4000   James    4                   2                  John
```

query (id =  3000)

```
Id     Name    LevelPosition  LeaveApprovalLevel LeaveApprovingManager 
3000   Nick       3                  2                 John
```

query (id =  2000)

```
Id     Name    LevelPosition  LeaveApprovalLevel LeaveApprovingManager 
2000   John       2                  2                 John
```

Also I want to check leave approving manager only upwards in the hierarchy.

query (id = 1000)

```
Id     Name    LevelPosition  LeaveApprovalLevel LeaveApprovingManager 
1000   Jack    1                 2               NULL
```

I wrote a CTE to get the manager with LeaveApproving bit set. Getting the employee with level is also straightforward. My issue is to get all these details in the same row.

So the question really is I got individual results for employee details and Leave Approving manager. How can I get this in a single row?

I managed to get individual queries for the following

employee details

```
 Id     ParentId  Name   Position 
 4000   3000      James   4

LeaveApprovalLevel  details

Level
2

LeaveApprovingManager details

 Id     ParentId  Name   
 2000   1000      John
```

How can I join these so that I will get this?

```
Id     Name    LevelPosition  LeaveApprovalLevel LeaveApprovingManager 
4000   James    4                   2                  John
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: *"I need"* isn't a question, it's a demand/request. What is your question here? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Your `ParentId` points to nowhere.

Comment: Note, as well, there is no `bool` type in SQL Server. You have `bit`, however, it is not a boolean value (though it is often used to represent one). They are, however, implicitly different as you cannot have a clause in the `WHERE` along the lines of `WHERE BitColumn` and expect it to work; you would need to do `WHERE BitColumn = 1`.

Comment: sorry, parent id changed

Comment: *"I wrote a CTE to get the manager with LeaveApproving bit set. Getting the employee with level is also straightforward. My issue is to get all these details in the same row."* Then why haven't you shown that attempt in your "question"? And please, do ask a question so we can answer what ever that is. We can't give you an answer if we don't have a question to answer.

Comment: Its because my actual tables are different. I just used employee stuff so that I can avoid putting the actual table names in the public domain.

Comment: So, you have code, that you won't show us, that isn't working, and you have made a demand for us to do the work for you instead? I suggest at least reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) again, and updating your "question" with  question and a MRE. Like I said though, if you don't ask a question, we can't give you an answer. SO is a Q&A website after all, so if we don't know what the problem is, we can't offer a solution.

Comment: I updated the question again. I don't necessarily need the code. What I have is lack of understanding of merging different rows to form a single row. I was hoping to get some tips so that I could resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

- Get the hierarchy for the employee.
- Use `join`s to get the information on the flag you want.
- Use `join`s to bring back all the information you want.

As a query:

```
with cte as (
      select e.id, e.parentid, 1 as lev
      from employee e
      where id = 4000
      union all
      select cte.id, e.parentid, lev + 1
      from cte join
           employee e
           on e.id = cte.parentid
     )
select e.*, el.*
from cte join
     employee e
     on cte.id = e.id join
     employee el
     on cte.parentid = el.id join
     EmployeeLevel eml
     on cte.parentid = eml.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT e1.Id, e1.Name, el1.Position as LevelPosition, el2.Position as LeaveApprovalLevel,  e2.Name as LeaveApprovingManager FROM Employee e1 INNER JOIN EmployeeLevel el1 ON e1.LevelId = el1.Id LEFT JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.ParentId = e2.Id LEFT JOIN EmployeeLevel el2 ON e2.LevelId = el2.Id;
```

Here is the response

[Check, here is the working Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pDKULGcadoMSowTKhmKhvb/1)

Comment: Note that there is only one LeaveApproving manager in the data(John). He is only one in the level (2) which is marked for Leave approval. The fiddle query returns wrong answer. Because of the hierarchy we need to use CTE I suppose